# cant install fglrx (proprietary ATI driver) for HD 8970M

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx, proprietary

I have an AMD HD 8970M video card and Ubuntu 13.10.
I'm following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775) to the letter, except that I of course use the latest non-beta AMD drivers (13.12) instead of the old version mentioned in the guide.

I get as far as running

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Which comes back to me with

```
aticonfig: no supported adapters detected
```

When I run the driver shell script directly (not the package option) it says:

```
Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed.
```

What to do now?

Comment: That's simple, just wait for a driver that supports it.

Comment: This is not helpful. The 8970m was introduced in August 2013. The Catalyst 13.12 was released in December 2013. How come it doesn't support the GPU that is four months old already??

Comment: Good question. AMD provides the driver, so why don't you ask them. There is nothing we can do about it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of fglrx-13.35.1005 the HD8970 works okay now.